# Laravel Mail::send() do not really work with from

Tags: php, email, laravel

Probably someone can see what I'm doing wrong here. When I use `->from('test@example.com')` the mail sends just fine. But when i use `>from('test@hotmail.com')` the mail is not sent. Everything is done in mail configuration as well.

```
        $data = array("content" => Input::get("content"));
        Mail::send("emails.text", $data, function($message)
        {
            $message->to('toMe@myDomain.com')
            ->from('test@hotmail.com' , 'Contact form message!');
        });
```

Config:

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'mail.cornex.se',
'port' => 587,
'from' => array('address' => "christopher@cornex.se", 'name' => "Kristoffer"),
'encryption' => 'tls',
```

Comment: Can you post your mail configuration from `app/config/mail.php`? (driver, host, from, port, encryption)

Comment: @c-griffin, I have updated the main post with your request!

Answer (score 0):

Hotmail uses Outlook SMTP.  Try this:
You may need to make slight modifications, but make note of the `host`, specifically.

```
'driver' => 'smtp',
'host' => 'smtp-mail.outlook.com',
'from' => array('address' => "christopher@cornex.se", 'name' => "Kristoffer")
'port' => 587, // or 25
'encryption' => 'tls',
```

Comment: Are this really right? I just wanna set from so I can see what email the user have put into the contact form field. The host is for my main web email

Comment: By the looks of it, you're trying to use hotmail as your SMTP gateway, correct?  Are you saying that `from()` will actually be a variable of a user's email address?

Comment: Yeah `from()` should be the email the user have put into the contact form field.

Comment: Ah, ok.  So disregard my comment about `host`.  Is it just that you aren't getting the message?  If the headers mismatch, it is probable that it is getting blocked or classified as spam.  Check your log at `app/storage/logs/laravel.log` for errors.  Additionally, if you set your driver to `log`, it will simulate a sent, but print to your log file. [this](http://laravel.com/docs/mail#mail-and-local-development) may also help in development.  Ii use [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com) and haven't had any problems.  Send `from()` your site admin address and set `replyTo()` address as the user's.